# Is this correct? If so, can it be proved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am studying fractions in school, and I need a bit of help.
Is this theory correct?:

$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}$$
Rule: $w$ is a factor of $x$ or $y$,
$$y = x+w$$
$$z = \frac{1}{w}xy  $$
For example, if
$$x=12, \qquad y=16, \qquad w=4  $$
then $z=48$

because:
$$\frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{48}$$
as $16 = 12 + 4$, and
$$z= \frac{1}{4} \times 12 \times 16$$

*Is it true that $w$ must be a factor of $x$ or $y$ for this to work?*

Comment: No: $w=9, x=3, y=12$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused by what exactly you are asking, but here we go.

Suppose $y=x+w$. Then $$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$ implies $$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+w}=\frac{w}{x(x+w)}=\frac{1}{z}.$$
Thus $z=\frac{x(x+w)}{w}=\frac{xy}{w}$.

I only used that $y=x+w$, you don't have to assume $w$ is a factor of anything.

Examples: pick any $x$ and $w$ such that $w$ is not a factor of $x$ and not a factor of $x+w$ (in fact the latter is a redundant statement).

Comment: Little note: It is compulsory that $w|x^2$

Comment: If you want an integer solution, yeah. Judging by the question, the OP probably wants that. So you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Exodd: What does "compulsory" mean here? Who is compelled?

Comment: Thank you for your help. If fractions with non-integer denominators were allowed the theory would work for all fractions then?

Comment: Yes, it would work.